# How do I deploy my website on my office network?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, deployment, server

I want to deploy a website on my office network. Currently, I am using Tomcat server v8.5.

The plan is to host the website on a dedicated machine, so that other employees can access it by connecting to the office network using the `localhost:8080<App_Name>` as URL. Any idea on how I can make this happen?

Currently, I have deployed the .war file on the tomcat server, but are there any more configurations to be done on any of the client or server machines through which the employees can access the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use localhost as a domain name for your server in a local network because by default localhost points to the ip Address 127.0.0.1 which is the local machine from which you access the network. You should ask your admin at work to give your machine a dedicated IP address so it won't change when you reboot your server. You can then access your app by visiting for example 192.168.0.44:8080 if 192.168.0.44 is the IP address that he gave you.

In the next step he could set up a DNS entry locally so that your server is reachable with a specific domain name. If you don't have an admin but access to the network router you can try to do it yourself. It depends on your router if this is possible or not. Here is an example on how to do this with a linksys router: https://www.linksys.com/dk/support-article?articleNum=164492

This won't work if the router is not set as the default dns server on your clients. For example if someone configured their machine that it uses google dns server instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am now able to access the web app on the server using the servers IPV4 address. However, Is there any way I can setup a local DNS, just to make the URL look a little more specific. For example now I am using 192.168.100.222:8080/<AppName>/, can I setup a local DNS which only has the app name?

Comment: You can try if your local router allows setting DNS entries. Normally when machines connect to your network the router tells them the address of the DNS server they should use. Oftentimes the router itself acts as this DNS server and you might be able to set custom DNS entries there.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

check out this

https://www.dotscreated.com/deploy-web-app-offline-on-local-network/

may be it will help u